# HTML table border double line

Tags: css, html, html-table

I tried to create a table with border (on every cell). Everything is okay, just the following part not:
[image: wrong line width]
The first cell has double wide top border.

The css contains:

```
table { white-space-collapse:collapse; border-collapse:collapse; }  
table tr td, table tr th { padding: 0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:middle; }

table.bordered tr{border: 1px solid black;}   
table.bordered td{border: 1px solid black;}
```

The HTML code:

```
`<table class="bordered">
    <th>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="tHead">Memory slot</div></td>
            <td><div class="tHead">Frequency [MHz]</div></td>
            <td><div class="tHead">Output power [dBm]</div></td>
        </tr>
    </th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="mid" id="mS0Num"></div></td>
            <td><div class="mid" id="mS0Freq"></div></td>
            <td><div class="mid" id="mS0OP"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="mid" id="mS1Num"></div></td>
        ...
</tbody>
```

`

I want to make the first cell border as the other cell borders. How can i do this?

Comment: Create a demo using snippet instead of posting image.

Comment: Add you HTML code for the table as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LwT7k/3/)

**CSS**

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#table td, #table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```